List of statistics questions
I recently watched some Blackpenredpen YouTube videos on "100 Calculus Limits/Derivatives/Integrals (Parts 1 and 2)" and found them very helpful for refreshing my knowledge and learning new things about calculus. Similarly, I’d like to do the same for statistics.
I’m looking for a structured list of statistics exercises that spans the entire field and is organized from easy to advanced difficulty. My goal is to refresh and deepen my understanding of statistics, especially its connections to mathematics.
If possible, I’d like the list to include up to 500 exercises (or more, if necessary) to ensure comprehensive coverage of the subject, from easy to hard.

Can you please clarify your question a bit?  This Q&A site is designed to provide a place for mathematics educators to give advice to other mathematics educators. It appears that you are looking for a text for self-study, which is maybe marginally on-topic here.  Also, "...exercises that spans[sic] the entire field..." is way too broad.  Can you focus the question quite a bit to a particular area of study?

Xander, I think ("Bayesian prior") that since the questioner also mentioning his watching of neophyte calculus videos, he's looking for a college starter version of statistics.  Perhaps even non calculus based, but if there's calculus, at an easy level (pdf graph, e.g.)  Not any of the crazy theory stuff, that is literally part of the field.

Xander, and you're probably right that this site is for educators to discuss teaching (or their jobs or whatever), not for student advice on textbooks...but...meh.


I’m looking for a structured list of statistics exercises ... to ensure comprehensive coverage of the subject, from easy to hard.

You are looking for a statistics textbook.
The best free one as of 2024 is located at OpenStax. You can also look for other textbooks! This question could also help you choose one.

In addition to the Schaum's Outline that I already recommended on the other question, I would look at the other drill books that come up when you do a Google search (e.g. 'Humongous Book of' brand and the 'Dummy's 1001 Stats problems').  They seem cheap (under $20, especially used) and have high user ratings.
It sounds like you want a structured drill book, more than a standard "textbook".  The latter will be heavier on the writing describing the topic. (The writing is geared to professors, who select text books.)  And most "textbooks" will typically only have answers to half or less of the drill.  (Which makes independent use worse.)
Can still get something out of a standard text, of course.  Nothing stops you from concentrating on the drill/examples within a textbook and minimizing the reading of explication (perhaps just when you have a question).  Many students already follow this strategy.  ;)    But there's a reason why there is a niche market for drill-oriented books. (Because there is student market demand, duh.)
